# Rails TextHelper truncate method: Check for more complex separator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to use regular expressions for more complex separators in this?

```
truncate(content, :length=>60, :separator=>' ')
```

Checking for the standard space as the separator (' ') isn't enough for me. My main goal is to **check for \n (enter/a new line)**, so if someone knows how to do that please let me know.

I was also curious if there was a way to check for a broader range of things.

**Edit:**
Sorry, more details: I hope to **have a separator like => / \r\n/** so the truncate method will separate around both spaces and new lines when determining where to put ellipsis, but I can't use regexps. See the problem?

Comment: Could you expand on "My main goal is to check for \n (enter/a new line)"? I get the "check for" part, but where would you add it, at the end?

Comment: Added details; is it clearer now?

Comment: I think I'm getting where you're going with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Truncate](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate) only allows for two optional arguments, `:omission` and `:separator`. You can see by the following code for truncate that it is only set up to work with a string for `:separator`:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb, line 38
def truncate(length, options = {})
  text = self.dup
  options[:omission] ||= "..."

  length_with_room_for_omission = length - options[:omission].mb_chars.length
  chars = text.mb_chars
  stop = options[:separator] ? (chars.rindex(options[:separator].mb_chars, length_with_room_for_omission) || length_with_room_for_omission) : length_with_room_for_omission

  (chars.length > length ? chars[0...stop] + options[:omission] : text).to_s
end
```

With this being said, you should be able to accomplish what you are trying to achieve (if I understand the situation correctly) with something like this (switch newlines and whatnot to spaces, first):

```
truncate(content.gsub(/\s/i, ' '), :length=>60, :separator=>' ')
```

If this is too simple, you could probably come up with exactly what you want, with a fairly simple modification to the official `truncate()` code...

Comment: Thanks - I got the main concept from here! I ended up doing this: truncate(content.gsub(/\n/, ' '), :length=>60, :separator=>' ')

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
truncate(content, :length => 60, :separator => '\n')
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but I would like to check for both spaces and new lines. I think the regexp would be / \r\n/, but I can't put that in. See the problem?